# After update to Sonarqube 6.4 java script coverage exclusion does not work

Tags: javascript, sonarqube, code-coverage

After updating Sonarqube from 6.3 to 6.4 java script coverage exclusion does not work like before. We use JavaScript plugin in version 3.0.0.4962, sona-gradle-plugin 2.4 and we exclude our js-tests with "sonar.coverage.exclusions","**/*-test.js" from the coverage analysis.
After the update the *-test.js" are counted again for the coverage.
Is this a bug or do we have to do something differently?

Answer (score 0):

This is in fact a comment, but I don't have the rating to comment.

I've tried and failed to reproduce your issue (with SonarQube 6.4 and SonarJS 3.0.0.4962). Do you perhaps have quotes around your path? Anyway, here is my working sonar-project.properties :

```
sonar.projectKey=test-coverage
sonar.projectName=Test Coverage
sonar.projectVersion=1.0

sonar.sources=.

sonar.javascript.lcov.reportPaths=coverage.lcov

sonar.coverage.exclusions=**/*-test.js
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The quotes are from the gradle script. It worked that way with 6.3. or perhaps the change from the sonar gradle plugin from 2.3 to 2.5 changed the behaviour. Anyway, the workaround is currently okay for us. If there is some time, I'll check it with new versions.